# how to add link in gridview (asp.net)?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ado.net

I have made a gridview in asp.net vb. and i want to add a link on id columns i want to make a link which can land to new page etc http://localhost/defualt.aspx?id= (id row from datarow) . Is it possible with gridview? code is following

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="EmployeeID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EmployeeID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
            SortExpression="FirstName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NwindConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NwindConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [EmployeeID], [LastName], [FirstName] FROM [Employees]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use HyperLinkField

```
     <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="EmployeeID" 
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/default.aspx?id={0}"
                            DataTextField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="EmployeeID" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the BoundField for EmployeeID and replace TemplateField. Try this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmployeeID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="EmployeeID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                        CommandName="" PostBackUrl='<%# "http://localhost/defualt.aspx?id=" & Eval("EmployeeID") %>' Text='<%# Eval("EmployeeID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```