# Gridview Hypelink values based on row value and column header identifier

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a gridview in vb.net wich provides a performance value of a list of business names for the previuous week, current week and next week as follows:

```
LOB   W-1   W    W+1
--------------------
AMEX  10   15    30
PPR   11   12    14 
REM   12   11    10
```

What I need is for this values to be a hyperlink that opens another window based on the business name and the week to provide further detail. For example, if you want further datail of the value 15 for AMEX and the current week (W) then by pressing the value 15 a new window will open with information for AMEX for the current week.

I have the gridview created but I can not figure out how to do the hyperlinks. Any ideas?

See below code.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DateSelection" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="134px" >
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button_Update" runat="server" Text="UPDATE" />
<br />
    <br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
    GridLines="None" ForeColor="#333333">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LOB" HeaderText="LOB" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="W-1" HeaderText="W-1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="W" HeaderText="W" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="W+1" HeaderText="W+1" />         
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

vb code

```
    Dim dv_Groups As New System.Data.DataView
    Dim dt_Groups As New System.Data.DataTable

    dv_Groups = Group.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
    dt_Groups = dv_Groups.ToTable()

    Dim dv_Main As New System.Data.DataView
    Dim dt_Main As New System.Data.DataTable

    dv_Main = SQL_Main.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
    dt_Main = dv_Main.ToTable()

    Dim dt_Report As New DataTable()
    dt_Report.Columns.Add("LOB", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt_Report.Columns.Add("W-1", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt_Report.Columns.Add("W", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt_Report.Columns.Add("W+1", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    Dim FindRow() As DataRow
    Dim SearchText As String
    Dim DateS As Date
    Dim DateWeek As String
    DateS = DateSelection.SelectedItem.Text
    Dateweek = Format(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, DateS)) 

    For i As Integer = 0 To dt_Groups.Rows.Count - 1
        dt_Report.Rows.Add()
        dt_Report.Rows(i)(0) = dt_Groups.Rows(i)(0)
        SearchText = "LOB like '" & Trim(dt_Report.Rows(i)(0)) & "%'  And DateWeek = '" & Dateweek - 1 & "' "
        FindRow = dt_Main.Select(SearchText)
        dt_Report.Rows(i)(1) = FindRow(0).Item("A_SVL").ToString
        SearchText = "LOB like '" & Trim(dt_Report.Rows(i)(0)) & "%'  And DateWeek = '" & Dateweek & "' "
        FindRow = dt_Main.Select(SearchText)
        dt_Report.Rows(i)(2) = FindRow(0).Item("A_SVL").ToString
        SearchText = "LOB like '" & Trim(dt_Report.Rows(i)(0)) & "%'  And DateWeek = '" & Dateweek + 1 & "' "
        FindRow = dt_Main.Select(SearchText)
        dt_Report.Rows(i)(3) = FindRow(0).Item("S_SVL").ToString
    Next

    GridView1.DataSource = dt_Report
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HyperLinkField or TemplateField to add links to your gridview, as shown here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8859655/849182